# jQuery autocomplete numbers

Tags: jquery, json, regex, mongodb, autocomplete

I'm trying to use the jQuery autocomplete function over a text input box to retrieve all the numeric values, inside a MongoDB collection, which match the input. The problem is that all the values in the collection are numeric values and the regex pattern I'm using isn't working (perhaps does it recognize only strings?).

To get the numeric value from the input box, I'm using this code:

```
var ib = parseInt(jQuery("#id_input_box").val())
```

And this is the query in MongoDB:

```
{"input_box": {"$regex" : ".*" + ib + ".*" , "$options":"i"} }
```

It must be a regex pattern 'cause I need to retrieve all the values that contains "ib" as numbers.

Ex: values in collection (23,123,223,4239), ib = 23 should match them all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've scripted a workaround which gives me all the records in the collection and for each one of them I casted the numeric values into string. Then, I've built an array with all the collection's records that contains the submitted value in the input box. Then, at last, I did a query on the collection, where all the "input_box" values are contained in the array I've built.

This will cost a lot once the collection increases in number of records, but I couldn't find any better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use ajax

```
$('.your_search_input).keyup(function(){
 var value = $('.your_search_input).val();
    $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'search.php', 
                data: { param: value }, 
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                $('html').append(data) //append the data that contains matching number to anywhere you want
                    }
        });
}
```

php file (search.php) shoild seem like so.

```
if(isset($_GET['param'])){
$param= $_GET['param'];
}
$sql1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id LIKE %:input% ORDER BY");
$sql1->bindValue('input',$param);
$sql1->execute();
```

Comment: Doing it with ajax solved the problem, thank you. I wasn't sure that I could use php queries on a MongoDB collection, since I am doing queries all the time in NoSQL. Thanks anyway :)